# How to add slug in Django Web-application

Tags: django, django-models, slug

Here is the problem: I'm trying to 'fresh' my django web blog, so instead of having `/post/2/` I want to have slugged link that's exactly like my title (smth like this: `/post/today-is-friday`

Here is some code, I've tried couple of things, but there is nothing working:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="images/None/no-img.jpg")
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView, UserPostListView

urlpatterns = [
    #Blog section
    path("", PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path("user/<str:username>", UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path("<slug:slug>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path("post/new/", PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path("<slug:slug>/update/", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path("<slug:slug>/delete/", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path("about/", views.about, name="blog-about"),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
]
```

*user_posts.html*(this is for accessing blog post itself)

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <h1 class='mb-3'>Post by {{ view.kwargs.username }} ({{ page_obj.paginator.count }})</h1>
  {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2 author_title" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">@{{ post.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"N d, Y" }}</small>
          <div>
            <!-- category section -->
            <small class="text-muted">
              Categories:&nbsp;
              {% for category in post.categories.all %}
              <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
                {{ category.name }}
              </a>&nbsp;
              {% endfor %}
            </small>
          </div>


        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|slice:200 }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

*post_form.html*(It's for creating a new post, have trouble with redirecting after post created)

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
              {{ form|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
             <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to change the value of the `slug` field before saving, you can use signals.

Also the `slugify` method of django is located in `django.utils.text` not `django.template.defaultfilters`.

**urls.py**

```
# ...
path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
# ...
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify
import string


class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    # do not override save method here 


def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


def unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=None):
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    else:
        slug = slugify(instance.title)

    class_ = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = class_.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
    if qs_exists:
        new_slug = f"{slug}-{random_string_generator(size=5)}"
        return unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Post)
def post_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)
```

Those two functions, `unique_slug_generator` and `random_string_generator`, together will guaranty that you won't have same slug on two posts, even if the title of those posts are same! (it will add some randomly generated string at the end)

#### Edit

In your html template for `user_posts.html`, replace

```
<h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
```

with

```
<h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
```

Also, in your **view** (not template) of `post_form`, you should override `get_success_url` like this:

```
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

#### Edit 2 (for more clarification)

First, we need a url for each post, we implement it as:

```
path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

Next, you should change your previous links to the `post-detail`. These include your 1)template links and 2)links in the views/models:

In your templates, wherever you have `{% url 'post-detail' post.pk %}`, you should change that to `{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}`.

and in your views/models, you should change `reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})` tp `reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})` (not `self.object.slug`)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I have some problems. I can't figure out what's wrong: `NoReverseMatch at /post/new/

Reverse for 'post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']`

Comment: You are redirecting the user to `post-detail` after creating a new post with wrong reverse kwargs; use `reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})` in your `get_successful_url` of post creation view.

Comment: I have this line of code to access my blog post. Should I correct in it something, because when I'm clicking on `h2`, it wants to redirect me to `/4/`, but when I myself type in the search bar for example `beautiful-life`, it redirects me to the blog page. Everything seems to work well, but I need help to figure this problem with redirecting

Comment: Please include this code so that I find the problem; but basically, in your templates, you should use something like this: `{% url 'post-datail' post.slug %}`

Comment: One moment, I'll include extra code, thank you for your patient :)

Comment: Check the edit, if you have struggle implementing `get_success_url` of post creation, also include your **view** code.

Comment: So, you just need a little change in `get_absolute_url` of your `Post` model: `return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})`

Comment: also got an error after adding post.slug: `No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.`

Comment: I'll update my urls.py, maybe I did smth wrong there

Comment: @CODE make sure you have `self.slug` not `post.slug` in your `get_absolute_url`. I test that and it's working. When you get that error?

Comment: i have this line of code for `get_absolute_url`: `return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})`, as you said to add. I don't know, but when I'm trying to click on h2 tag it is showing in the down left corner of my browser `/4/` instead of `/milky-way-show`

Comment: I know, maybe I'm sooo boring with my questions, anyway, you did the job with helping me to implement slug in my blog. If you feel bored by this bug fixing, I can close the question and give you point-up. But if you don't mind to help me and fix this problem, you'll make my day! :)

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a solid foundation on django concepts... But I am writing an edit to the answer for more clarification... keep waiting :) Meanwhile you can check my blog implementation [here](https://github.com/Pedram-Parsian/Library-Management-System/tree/master/blog)